# javascript syntax error in IE 9

Tags: javascript, html, storage

I keep getting a javascript syntax error with the "else" in the following code block:

```
                        if ( validateme.length > 0 && !isValidEmailAddress( validateme ) )  { 
                                //alert("invalid email");
                                $('#validation_error').html("oops! That's an invalid email address");
                        }       sessionStorage.setItem("form_error", "true");
                        else {
                                sessionStorage.setItem("form_error", "false");
                        }
                        break;
```

I tried the same page in Firefox. But it doesn't have any errors listed in the console.

Suggestions would be appreciated.  In the interim, I'm going to try in Chrome as well to see if I get any errors...

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in front of the "else", just look where your

```
sessionStorage.setItem("form_error", "true");
```

is located. You should put that "setItem" inside the if-Block, and not after it ;)

Comment: doh!  That's it. I've been looking at this too long!

Comment: This happens to everyone, always those small things that keep us bugging :)

Comment: Lol, I wonder if that is the fastest 6 "helpful" points ever awarded here.

Answer (score 0):

`}       sessionStorage.setItem("form_error", "true");
                        else {`

bad bracketing

Should be:

`sessionStorage.setItem("form_error", "true"); }else {`